# What is the obfuscation method utilised in Playdead's 'LIMBO' video game?

Tags: obfuscation

The game uses Unity3D engine, perhaps with a custom render pipeline. Reports have been made, it is not possible to disassemble it. How did they achieve that?

Comment: Which reports? Can you link to some?

Comment: @nobody can you disprove first?

Comment: that's a rather spurious response. Disprove what? You made a claim, and the (legitimate) question was raised where the claim comes from. Given this was migrated to our site, I second the request. One of the first tasks a reverse engineer usually does is reconnaissance. And looking at those reports could provide first insights.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what do you mean by "custom render pipeline" and "not possible to disassemble it", but I quickly checked my steam version, and all I can find is the SteamStub.
Once removed, the code is not obfuscated.

Comment: Perhaps you could outline what procedure you used to come to your conclusion.

Comment: and how does DRM Manager influence source code and game resources?

Comment: Most of (any?) games coming from Steam are packed with their solution. One way to quickly check that is the presence of a section named `.bind`.
This [link](https://www.pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/User:Cyanic/Steam_DRM) explains it better than me.
The game doesn't use Unity3D, @ivan866 could you share your source?

Comment: @wisk the source mentioned in question is a single comment on Steam community pages; the notion that it uses Unity3D is (perhaps erratically) extrapolated from the fact that its successor, 'INSIDE', uses it, which is stated on Wikipedia page